# parameter pollution for post/put API request

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to prevent parameter pollution for POST/PUT request with json (in spring boot). If post/put json request is from client and before reaching to back-end service if attackers/hackers modified json then how to prevent this parameter pollution?

I have gone through many websites but could not get it clarified. 
help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution I can suggest here to use client side encryption to add additional parameters and verify the request parameters on server side.

```
{
 'firstname' : 'foo',
 'lastname' : 'bar',
 'secret' : MD5(firstname+lastname+datetime)
}
```